# How to store child record while parent is being created

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I have a form for creating/editing an Excursion record, which `has_many :excursion_images`.

In this form, the nested `excursion_images` are created by a js with a remote call ([Fine Uploader](https://fineuploader.com/)).

This solution works perfectly on edit Excursion, but not on creating, as the parent doesn't yet have an `id`.

I have a solution but not sure if there is a better alternative:

1. allowing the excursion_image to be created without a excursion.
2. creating a hidden field with an "image_code" on the _new form.
3. when creating an excursion_image, inside the form, save the corresponding "image_code" on an attribute.
4. when saving the excursion, find all excursion_image with the "image_code".

Doesn't seem very efficient! Is there any other way?

Comment: Or require excursion to be created with some basic info before uploading images. If later creation of excursion fails - you will mark existed excursion as cancelled

Comment: I don't want to hinder the experience, i like to have everything on the same view, if a user wants to upload images first, i'd rather let him.
I guess creating the empty excursion beforehand could be a fine solution too, but this also rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: You can persist experience, by creating excursion with first uploaded file.

Comment: "Empty" excursion will play exactly same role as "image_code" you are using right now, but in more comprehensible way

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have come up with is perfect. It does not seem very efficient but that is the only way. I don't think there is any workaround to store child before the parent.

I myself had quite a trouble with the similar situation before I ended up doing exactly what you have done.

Just that you will have to delete all the images, periodically, where Excursion is `nil` (as per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594948/how-to-store-child-record-while-parent-is-being-created/50595419#comment88201216_50595419) by @paul-noe)

Comment: Yes, and it can be done in a simpler way by periodically deleting any image where excursion is nil.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already looked into it but I believe `inverse_of` can be used to solve issues like this, there's some good explanation [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations/)

It basically helps you to work with associated record that are in the memory

Comment: Interesting, definately better than what i was using (step 1), the problem is that this requires both object to be sent simultaneously, but fineuploader sends a request as soon as the file is uploaded, which seems better.